# Finding location of the device

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geolocation

I want to develop an app in HTML/JS where if the user has internet on and his app on , then I can locate his location in the google map.

Moreover, if his location changes, I can also know that.

I know app like FInd my Friend on iOS or FInd my iphone/Ipad on iOS are there, but how is it possible in html 5/ JS ??

If you can share a link or present some idea, that would be great.

I googled it up and if I have the co-ordinates i can get it on google map. But, how to get the coordinates from other device, if just his app is on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the navigator get the user's current position:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (location)
{
     console.log(JSON.stringify(location, null, 4);
})
```

or watch their position:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (location)
{
     console.log(JSON.stringify(location, null, 4);
})
```

[See here for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation)

Comment: @Iyaad  I want to find the location of another device. How is that possible ? Can you share me a link

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML 5 to get the users location.  However, keep in mind that Google charges for the service (it's free with limits and conditions), both users have to accept the request from your site to access their location, and you can't access their location when they aren't actually in the browser on your site

Comment: I believe you can make 2500 requests a day. That sounds like a lot, and it may be plenty. However every time the page loads, and ANY action is made it counts.          Here is the link to their docs https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: I want to find the location of another device. How is that possible ? Can you share me a link

Comment: You can only do it if the other device is on your site. Then you will  want to get the coordinates and put them in a database.

Comment: other device on my site means ?? If he is in same city, then is it possible ?

Comment: If they close the browser, you can't get their location.  If they are in the browser and on your page your good to go

Answer (score 0):

Getting the location of the device can be done using the HTML5 Geolocation API.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/MattSmith/Gf3VZ/).

However, if you're attempting to get the location of another person's device you're probably going to need to build a web app that does that (some kind of RESTful that users can login into and/or share their geolocation info).

```
// create google map
function GoogleMap(position) {
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 20,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: location,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: "This is your location"
    });

    map.setCenter(location);
}
// show error if location can't be found
function showError() {
    alert("Location can't be found");
}
//execute geolocation
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GoogleMap, showError);
}
else {
    alert("Your browser does not support Geolocation.");
}
```

Comment: I want to find the location of another device. How is that possible ? Can you share me a link

Comment: To my knowledge that can't be done using the Geolocation API this way. The other device(s) would need to allow their location to be tracked. So you'd need to have that device logged into some kind of web service where the device user was allowing the device to be actively tracked.